# Should we close this question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[The question: End of the main storyline](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37321/3610) seems to *just* about fit as a valid question (Is the game really over when I've finished the main quest?), but it's quite poorly asked and both answers on it are not really answers, and the way the question is phrased would seem to invite more answers in a similar vein. Do we allow the question to continue to exist?

Answer (score 2):

It feels like a long version of the question "is this it", commonly raised when one reaches a disappointing ending.

Nevertheless, the question "is this it" *can* be phrased in a non-rhetorical way, which is what this particular question is trying to do. So while I wouldn't say it's a great question, I don't see anything so wrong about it that it would deserve a closure.